# validate dynamic form of inputs

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve that every time there is an empty entry, it warns me in an alert "there are empty fields" and also put the focus on an empty entry and so on until the last empty entry, if they are all full of data, the button says: "filled successfully", in an alert it also has unique fields that must also be validated, I mean those two inputs of the save button must have yes or yes data added to the table for the button to be enabled What is needed is

1 the button should be disabled and if there is nothing added in the second table, do not enable the button even though it is the search field with data and the field next to it with data, that is, there must be some field added in the table second table so that the save button has just been enabled

2 The validations() function does not work for me in this function, the button should be enabled if there are all the fields with data, also those that are created with the add button

```js
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = tbody.querySelector('.ItemCarrito>.form__element-input_cantidad>#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
 // input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
 if (input === null) {
  // manejar error.
  //console.log('No se logró encontrar el error');
  return;
}

if (typeof input.value === 'undefined' || input.value === null) {
  input.value = cantidad;
} else {
  input.value = (input.valueAsNumber + cantidad);
  // podrias tratar también con
  // input.value = +input.value + cantidad;
  // input.value = +input.value + cantidad ?? cantidad;
}

updateCantidadNuevo(input);
//console.log(id, input);
}


const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')

addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);

});



function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
 
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;


  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod, cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

 
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
    
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;" >
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

    



    
    
    <td class="form__element-input_cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}"  class="shopping-cart-quantity-input cantidad" type="number"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>

        <td class="form__element-input_precio">
     <input  id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"     min="0">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>

     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
    }






function validations(form) {
  var field;
  var i=0;
  do{
    field=form[i];
    if (field.value=='') {
      field.focus();
      alert('The field ' + field.name + ' is blank, please enter a value!');
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  } while( i <= counter);
  alert("everything is OK, submiting the form!");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" onsubmit="return validations(this)">
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo"class="form-control" placeholder="buscar" required>
                
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar"  />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>cantidad </TH>
            <TH>precio </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the translate the 4th paragraph of the question to English.

Comment: There's no code that displays the message "empty fields" or sets focus.

Comment: that's what it takes

Comment: What are you expecting `if (([text] + '.value') == '')` to do? It's concatenating strings, so the result can never be equal to an empty string.

Comment: What is `f.numTexts`? There's no input with that name.

Comment: if you're right, but then how to do it, that's my code,
f.numTexts should be equal to form1 . input to the name attribute, do you have a solution, please raise it as an answer

Comment: @Barmar, I already changed the expectation code and added what I want to do.

Comment: `[text] + '.value'` doesn't do what you think it does. It's certainly not how you get the value of anything.

Comment: When you convert `[text]` to a string, you get `'txt'`. Then the concatenation produces `'txt.value'`. So that `if` statement is basically doing `if ('txt.value' == '')`, which can never succeed.

Comment: If you want all the text inputs in a form, you can use `document.forms.form1.querySelector("input[type='text']")`. BTW, you need `name="form1"` in the `<form>`

Comment: There's so much wrong in your code, you need to start over and think more carefully about what you're doing.

Comment: recently. I was correcting but the validations function does not work for me,                                           @Barmar